# Combining NLP (text) and numeric data to build a model

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, regression, data-science

I have a dataset with the following features

```
data = {
description:'the tea was amazing, had great taste.'
country:'Chile'
year: 1980
designation:'random'
points: 80
}
```

I am looking for a way to use these features to build a model to predict points.

Description seems to hold alot of information about points.

How do i feed this data into the model and also which model?

Comment: what are you asking exactly? which machine learning model are you picked for the solution? how do you feed the data?

Comment: This seems a bit too broad for SO

Comment: @shahaf i am asking which model to pick and also how to feed in the data

Answer (score 1):

As textual data cannot be given to a model directly, I suggest you to use embeddings to convert description to embeddings. If there are unique values of designations overall in your dataset you can one hot encode the designations. For countries you can also one hot encode them or also use character based embeddings to generate word based embeddings. Year and points don't need pre-processing. As I can assume by your problem your problem is a regression problem. You can try Sklearn's gradient boosting regressor or random forests regressor or any other regressor to get values.

```py
def loadGloveModel(gloveFile):
    print("Loading Glove Model")
    f = open(gloveFile,'r')
    model = {}
    for line in f:
        splitLine = line.split()
        word = splitLine[0]
        embedding = np.array([float(val) for val in splitLine[1:]])
        model[word] = embedding
    print("Done.",len(model)," words loaded!")
    return model
```

You can use this as (This file can be downloaded from glove site.)

```py
model=loadGloveModel("glove.6B.300d.txt")
```

```py
def averagewEmbeddings(line):

    line=str(line)
    average=model['x']
    length=0
    line=line.split(' ')
    for word in line:
        #for alphabet in word:
        length=length+1
        try:
            embed=model[word]
            average=average+embed
        except:
            average=average

    return ((average-model['x'])/length)
```

```py
embeddings=[]
for index,sen in enumerate(data.description):
    embeddings.append(averagewEmbeddings(sen))
```

embeddings will have embeddings of all your dataset you can later append them to your dataframe and remove the description column

Comment: Thanks for this! But is there any alternative to embeddings? Embeddings take too long to run

Comment: If the texts in description are unique you can one hot encode them, but if they are not which most probably they won't be unique and can be changed there is no solution other then embeddings.